# How to parse json when entire string is enclosed in brackets

Tags: php, jquery, json

My json comes back from my PDO MySQL query as an associative array, as I intended, with the exception that the entire string is surrounded by two enclosing brakets. I'm not sure how to get around the brackets for parsing. Here is a brief example that is similar to the json that needs parsed. Any ideas as to an approach I might take, or how I can begin?

```
{
    "A": {
        "lat": "37.76506200",
        "lng": "-122.4196940"
    },
    "B": {
        "lat": "37.75225400",
        "lng": "-122.4184660"
    },
    "C": {
        "lat": "37.72198087",
        "lng": "-122.4474142"
    }
}
```

Comment: That's all the complete response/result you get? That's valid JSON, just parse it. Or do you have `(...)` around it? Then it seems to be malformed JSONP (missing function name). Set your server up to either serve proper JSON or proper JSONP.

Answer (score 2):

With *PHP*, take [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to account:

```
$array = json_decode($string, true); // where $string is your returned value
echo $array['C']['lng']; // will print -122.4474142
```

---

With *jQuery* you can do it with:

```
var res = $.parseJSON(string);
console.log(res.C.lng); // returns -122.4474142
```

And finally with *vanilla javascript* (if JSON is supported)

```
var res = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(res.C.lng);
```

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response.  I neglected to mention, however, that I am trying to parse it with jQuery, but am new to jQuery. I tried both eval() and $.getJSON, but can't seem to grab either the lat or lng elements. Ultimately, I'd like to be able to extract the parent nodes as well.

Comment: @BobMac Okay, I added other possibilities you have with jQuery/JavaScript